# Obtener coordenadas usando el método de click en Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, ionic, google-maps, ionic3

No puedo obtener las coordenadas usando el método de click en el googlemaps  ionic 3.

Estoy usando el método:

```
        this.map.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK).subscribe(
      (data) => {
          alert(data);
      }
  );
```

Como ven la imagen muestra lo siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no puedo obtener los valores por separado. No encuentro como.

Comment: data es array ¿no te sirve data[0]?

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias al compañero 
la solución es la siguiente .. (data es array)

```
       this.map.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK).subscribe(
      (data) => {
          alert("data[0].lat  " +  data[0].lat + " data[0].lng " + data[0].lng);
      }
  );
```